ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
I got this error while working on a Flutter project where I was trying to get profile description data from a Laravel backend. The backend is working fine but I couldn't figure out the problem, this code runs when the controller is initialized,  here's my flutter function:
LoginRequestEntity getProfileRequestEntity = new LoginRequestEntity();

    getProfileRequestEntity.token = state.to_token.value;

    var result = await UserAPI.get_Profile_description(params: getProfileRequestEntity);

    print("CODE ${result.code}.. MESSAGE ${result.msg}.... DATA ${result.data}");
    if (result.code == 0) {
      print("received");

    }

get_profile_descritption() :
static Future<BaseResponseEntity> get_Profile_description({
    LoginRequestEntity? params,
  }) async {
    var response = await HttpUtil().post(
      'api/get_profile_description',
      queryParameters: params?.toJson(),
    );
    r

eturn BaseResponseEntity.fromJson(response);
}
API :
public function get_profile_description(Request $request){
    $token = $request->token;
    $res = DB::table("users")->select("description")->where("token","=",$token)->first();
   
    return ["code" => 0, "data" => $res, "msg" => "success"];
}

BaseResponseEntity:
factory BaseResponseEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      BaseResponseEntity(
        code: json["code"],
        msg: json["msg"],
        data: json["data"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "counts": code ,
    "msg": msg ,
    "items": data,
  };
}

response from the server (using postman):
    "code": 0,
    "data": {
        "description": "just a test description"
    },
    "msg": "success"

logs :
I/flutter (26615): ** Instance "ChatProfileController" has been initialized. isError: [false]
E/flutter (26615): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
E/flutter (26615): #0      new BaseResponseEntity.fromJson (package:chatty/common/entities/base.dart:17:19)
E/flutter (26615): #1      UserAPI.get_Profile_description (package:chatty/common/apis/user.dart:31:31)
E/flutter (26615): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26615): #2      ChatProfileController.onInit (package:chatty/pages/message/chat/chatprofile/controller.dart:40:18)
E/flutter (26615): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26615): 


from which line you are getting this exception?

The error is not in the code you show. It's in BaseResponseEntity.fromJson or in UserAPI.get_Profile_description. My guess is that BaseResponseEntity.fromJson requires a String as argument but you are giving it a Map. Either the response you are getting from the api is not what you expect or you are handling the result wrong. But we can only tell for sure if you show us that code and also the response you get from the API

@Ivo I edited my question and added what you asked, please check it out

What's the type of data in BaseResponseEntity? If it's String then that's the problem, because as you can see data in the response is a Map. if you actually want the value of the "description" in the data then replace data: json["data"], with data: json["data"]["description"], and that should solve the problem then

@Ivo this worked! but I had to create another BaseResponseEntity called BaseDescriptionResponseEntity to prevent corrupting the previous code, I am sure there's a more optimized solution using the original  BaseResponseEntity, but until I understand this concept more this would have to suffice, thanks for your replies!
